# androidTestUtil in a library

Tags: android, testing

I have a library that contains test-butler. So in the library I do.

```
implementation 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-library:2.1.0'
```

and in the app consuming this library I do:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.github.mylib...'
```

now I am wondering how I could do the same for androidTestUtil - would like that the dependency:

androidTestUtil 'com.linkedin.testbutler:test-butler-app:2.1.0'

comes via the lib and does not need to be stated in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is directly possible unfortunately. The only thing I can think of is having a custom Gradle plugin that the app uses and having the plugin depend on AGP and add the `androidTestUtil` dependency on the Test Butler app. That seems very unnecessary though, and doesn't really save you much over the app just adding the dependency directly.